# Eclipse opening issue

Tags: java, eclipse, ide, editor

I've been trying to open eclipse via SSH on a linux machine but I keep getting this error. I've tried clearing disk space and running eclipse with the -clean flag but no luck. I've included the stack trace below in case it helps with debugging my issue.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Buffer size <= 0
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.<init>(BufferedInputStream.java:201)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.reliablefile.ReliableFile.getInputStream(ReliableFile.java:272)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.reliablefile.ReliableFileInputStream.<init>(ReliableFileInputStream.java:92)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.reliablefile.ReliableFileInputStream.<init>(ReliableFileInputStream.java:66)
at org.eclipse.osgi.storagemanager.StorageManager.updateTable(StorageManager.java:487)
at org.eclipse.osgi.storagemanager.StorageManager.open(StorageManager.java:708)
at org.eclipse.osgi.storage.Storage.getChildStorageManager(Storage.java:1749)
at org.eclipse.osgi.storage.Storage.getInfoInputStream(Storage.java:1766)
at org.eclipse.osgi.storage.Storage.<init>(Storage.java:126)
at org.eclipse.osgi.storage.Storage.createStorage(Storage.java:85)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxContainer.<init>(EquinoxContainer.java:75)
at org.eclipse.osgi.launch.Equinox.<init>(Equinox.java:31)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.startup(EclipseStarter.java:295)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:231)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:648)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:603)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1465)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1438)
```

Comment: What do you mean by "open eclipse via SSH on a linux machine"?

Comment: Sorry meant that I am SSh'ing from my laptop to a linux machine to access that machine's Eclipse

Comment: I do not think a command line shell will be able to run a graphical application thru SSH... Unless you have an X server on your laptop, and have set up X forwarding with SSH...